# CyberPanel webmail RainLoop not send/receive

Tags: centos, webmail, cyber-panel, rainloop

I'm using `cyberpanel` and webmail service is `RainLoop` but today I noticed that I can not send or receive mail, when I send email, it give me an error on `send` button

> Can't send message

Then I checked email logs:

```
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<info@test.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=57317, TLS, session=<py1wTNmqOrEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal postfix/submission/smtpd[57265]: connect from semikal.novalocal[::1]
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal postfix/cleanup[57269]: DE894140745C: message-id=<20200720060550.DE894140745C@test.com>
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal postfix/qmgr[1262]: DE894140745C: from=<double-bounce@test.com>, size=856, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal postfix/submission/smtpd[57265]: disconnect from semikal.novalocal[::1] ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal dovecot: imap(info@test.com)<57317><py1wTNmqOrEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>: Logged out in=11 out=474 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal postfix/pipe[57274]: DE894140745C: to=<postmaster@test.com>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown. Command output: lda(postmaster@test.com): Error: net_connect_unix(/var/run/dovecot/stats-writer) failed: Permission denied )
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal postfix/bounce[57276]: warning: DE894140745C: undeliverable postmaster notification discarded
Jul 20 06:05:50 semikal postfix/qmgr[1262]: DE894140745C: removed
Jul 20 06:05:51 semikal dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<info@test.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=57321, TLS, session=<q7t2TNmqQLEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jul 20 06:05:51 semikal dovecot: imap(info@test.com)<57321><q7t2TNmqQLEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>: Logged out in=96 out=1044 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
```

I also checked  `systemctl status postfix`, and result is:

```
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-07-16 18:51:37 UTC; 3 days ago
  Process: 1056 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1051 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1029 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1242 (master)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─ 1242 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─ 1262 qmgr -l -t unix -u
           ├─ 1670 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u
           └─57471 pickup -l -t unix -u

Jul 20 06:09:50 semikal.novalocal postfix/master[1242]: warning: process /usr...
Jul 20 06:09:50 semikal.novalocal postfix/master[1242]: warning: /usr/libexec...
Jul 20 06:10:50 semikal.novalocal postfix/smtpd[57465]: warning: /etc/postfix...
Jul 20 06:10:50 semikal.novalocal postfix/smtpd[57465]: warning: cannot get R...
Jul 20 06:10:50 semikal.novalocal postfix/smtpd[57465]: warning: TLS library ...
Jul 20 06:10:50 semikal.novalocal postfix/smtpd[57465]: warning: TLS library ...
Jul 20 06:10:50 semikal.novalocal postfix/smtpd[57465]: fatal: unexpected com...
Jul 20 06:10:51 semikal.novalocal postfix/master[1242]: warning: process /usr...
Jul 20 06:10:51 semikal.novalocal postfix/master[1242]: warning: /usr/libexec...
Jul 20 06:11:03 semikal.novalocal postfix/pickup[57471]: warning: /etc/postfi...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Any idea what is the problem? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Check you ban list your IP? Digital Ocean?

Comment: This is so hard to read that I cannot even tell whether your are actually trying to answer the question. If you request information before you can answer, please use your commenting privilege and delete this non-answer.

Comment: Um, actually one of the most common problems why you can't send/receive a letter is when your server's ip is blacklisted. You can test here, for example — https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

P.S. So I don't understand what your comment is for.

Comment: You are using words with question marks. That makes your post look like questions. If you intend your post to be an answer according to [answer] you should probably [edit] to make that more obvious. Otherwise users might perceive it as a question or a comment intended to clarify the question, by asking questions. You could also add the info from your post to the answer itself. Or to put it differently, if your post looks like a question (or two), chances are lower that it is judged a helpful answer.